# Minimal swaps for insertion sort

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I was solving a question in codeforces,which was about insertion sort,
the link:[the problem](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/362/C)
I am unable to solve the question the editorial says
           old - 2 * (di, ai + dj, aj - di, aj - dj, ai) - 1
I am not understanding the solution kindly help!
here is the editorial link:
https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/9584

Comment: Links rot, and when they do this question will become useless. Please include all of the important information in the question.

Comment: What is your container?  Is your data already sorted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an insertion sort into a linked list, the number of "swaps" is maximum of 2, if you consider inserting a new item as "swapping pointers".  The minimal number would be zero, if the key already exists; otherwise you'll *swap* one pointer when inserting before the head or after the tail.

The concept of an insertion sort is to keep the container sorted.  Most of the time is spent searching for the proper place in the container to insert the new datum.

For an array container, you would need to move elements in order to make room for the new data; which doesn't involve swapping.